# SparkContext implicit functions definition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading the latest code of Spark,there are comments:

```
  // The following implicit functions were in SparkContext before 1.3 and users had to
  // `import SparkContext._` to enable them. Now we move them here to make the compiler find
  // them automatically. However, we still keep the old functions in SparkContext for backward
  // compatibility and forward to the following functions directly.
```

I don't understand `Now we move them here to make the compiler find them automatically`, I would ask how spark could automatically find these implicit definitions,and put the implicit definition into scope, because user only create s SparkContext instance in their spark code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would ask how spark could automatically find these implicit
>   definition

It is not Spark, it is the Scala compiler. The compiler has several places it traces while compiling your code to try and find implicits. You can find them in [Where does Scala look for implicits?](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits)

Since these methods are defined on [`WritableConverter`](https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2776), anytime that type is in scope in one of the ways Scala looks for implicits, you'll automatically have these conversions in scope and be able to apply them.

Comment: Thanks @yuval-itzchakov for the helpful answer. I will check the implicits lookup you mentioned